# Nintex workflow Lazy approval - keep getting "already completed" mail

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, nintex, hmailserver

With Nintex workflow I made a workflow to test out Lazy Approval. That way a user gets a mail "The following item requires your approval"

[image]

When you answer that with a specific term, the item gets (dis)approved.

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on prem in a VM. Because of this I use `hMailServer` for the emails.

[image]

After getting the mail in the image above, I answer with "Yes", which approves and completes the workflow.

A minute after the item got put on approved, I get an email:

[image]

Every minute after that I get that same email.

My question: how to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it's a tricky one.

`hMailServer`needs a dropfolder, see [this tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/configure-hmailserver-for-sharepoint), to get the mails to SharePoint.

When SharePoint is done with a mail, it will delete this. If it can't delete it, it will think you resend it when the timer triggers again, and send you the mail with the error "*The task is no longer active. Another user may have already completed the task.*"

Give SharePoint the *Modify* (or full controll) permission and it's solved.

[image]